# django returns NoReverseMatch but it actually got the value

Tags: python, django

I'm making a shopping cart app for my website, and the function that worked yesterday was broken today.

I got `Reverse for 'delete-cart' with arguments '(4,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/delete_cart/<int:pk>']`error, But you can see that it has displayed the value of the parameter, proving that it got the value but still returned the not found error, why?
Here is my relevant code:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.myCartListView,name='my-cart'),
    url(r'^delete_cart/<int:pk>',views.delete_cart,name='delete-cart'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def myCartListView(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user:
        data = Cart.objects.filter(client=request.user)
    context['cart'] = data
    return render(request,'cart/my_cart.html',context)

@login_required
def delete_cart(request,pk):
    record = Cart.objects.get(pk=pk)
    record.delete()
    return redirect('cart/')
```

**my_cart.html**

```
{% for c in cart %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{c.item}}</th>
        <th>{{c.quantity}}</th>
        <th>{{c.price}}</th>
        <th>{{c.get_total_price}}</th>
        <th><a href="{% url 'delete-cart' c.id %}">DELETE</a></th>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: did you check that if there is an item with id of 4 ? and after deleting you are trying to redirect to your cart again. I think your error comes from that.

Comment: @ytsejam In case that object isn't exist it would throw another type of error - DoesNotExist.

Comment: @SergeyPugach yep that is why I have edited my comment, I understood error wrong.

Comment: Yes there is a record with id=4 in my database,I think there should be no problem with redirect, because it just returns to the shopping cart view after deleting a record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your url pattern to

```
path('delete_cart/<int:pk>/',views.delete_cart,name='delete-cart')
```

Comment: Oh god you're right sir, now I remember, thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify it as key value argument:

```
    <th><a href="{% url 'delete-cart' pk=c.id %}">DELETE</a></th>
```

Comment: It returns `Reverse for 'delete-cart' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 4}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/delete_cart/<int:pk>']`